# AngularJS with PHP - Authentication

Tags: php, angularjs

after successful login I set authentication token to each request

```js
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = authdata;
```

and when I debugging the code this part is really in sent header.

I'm sending requests to server where is PHP+Apache and in PHP code I can't acces to ['Authorization'] value, there isn't this key.

Please how should I work with this ['Authorization'] I tried PHP function getallheaders(), but there is no key like 'Authorization'? How should I check logged user token?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I right now found Apache under FastCGI is striping Authentication headers from HTTP requests (secure risk).

Solution is on my virtual server add to configuration:

```
FcgidPassHeader AUTHORIZATION
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only going to use Apache you might want to have a look at `apache_request_headers()`.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help.